# Using a dictionary key against the content of one cell to populate the cell of a new column with the related value

Tags: python, pandas

The Title is somewhat inelegant, but I'm not sure how to better phrase it. Anyway, say I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
Name    ZIP

Abe     22222
Beth    11111
Charlie 11111
David   22222
```

And I also have a dictionary:

```
categ_dict = {
    11111 : "Local",
    22222 : "Guest"
            }
```

I want to create a third column - `Category` - and populate it by comparing the content of each cell in the `ZIP` column against the the key-value pairs in the dictionary. If the content of that cell matches the key of a given pair, the `"Category"` cell in the same row is populated with the value of that pair. At the end, it should look like:

```
Name    ZIP     Category

Abe     22222   Guest
Beth    11111   Local
Charlie 11111   Local
David   22222   Guest
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df['Category'] = df.ZIP.map(categ_dict)` or `df['Category'] = df.ZIP.replace(categ_dict)`

Comment: Another alternative - `df['Category'] = df['ZIP'].apply(lambda val:categ_dict.get(val,replace with any default value))`

Comment: @sacul Wow, both fast and effective! They both work. Do you want to post it as answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: @JackFleeting, glad it helped! The duplicate takes care of it, though, I don't think it needs an answer posted (this post can act as a way to re-direct future users to the answer) :)

Comment: @sacul You're right - I guess that since the previous question was phrased as a mapping of a column against column, not column against a dictionary, it didn't come up in my search.

Comment: @Venkata Gogu - Thanks, your alternative works as well.

Comment: @JackFleeting Glad it helped you